# `Iterable[(int, int)]` tuple is not allowed in type hints

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

I have this very simple code:

```
from typing import List, Iterable

Position = (int, int)
IntegerMatrix = List[List[int]]

def locate_zeros(matrix: IntegerMatrix) -> Iterable[Position]:
    """Given an NxM matrix find the positions that contain a zero."""
    for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for col_num, element in enumerate(row):
            if element == 0:
                yield (col_num, row_num)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "type_m.py", line 6, in <module>
    def locate_zeros(matrix: IntegerMatrix) -> Iterable[Position]:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 970, in __getitem__
    (len(self.__parameters__), len(params)))
TypeError: Cannot change parameter count from 1 to 2
```

Why can't I have an iterable of Int pairs as the return type?

Both `-> Position` and `Iterable[Any]` work, just not `Iterable` and `Position` together don't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `typing.Tuple[int, int]` to declare the tuple type `Position`, not `(int, int)`.

Comment: But why does `foo() -> (int, int)` work and not `foo() -> Iterable[(int, int)]`?

Comment: Function annotations don't do anything; they are purely informational.  You can use any Python object as a type hint, and `(int, int)` certainly is a valid Python object.  You could also use `-> 42` or `-> super`.  It wouldn't be very useful, but syntactically correct.  `typing.Iterable` on the other hand is more specifically meant for type hints in function annotations, and it is designed to work together with the other type annotation classes in the `typing` module.